# python selenium script does not launch the browser from the vscode console, but runs locally from cmd

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, selenium-webdriver, launch

Machine windows 10.
Python selenium script does not launch the browser from the vscode console, but runs locally from cmd.

1. I'm downloading the project
2. Creating a venv
3. I download selenium with the pip install selenium command

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.python.org/")
driver.close()
```

**Project:**

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        18.09.2023      8:42                venv
-a----        18.09.2023      8:59          14263 geckodriver.log
-a----        18.09.2023      9:03            117 test.py
```

I see that venv is activated:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\user\test>
```

**Problem:**

When I run the script from the vscode console, nothing happens, no errors are even issued.

If I login on to the machine itself locally and run the script from cmd, the browser opens and works correctly

Pls help

I checked all the paths in vscode, they are correct

Answer (score 0):

Try running your script in **DEBUG** mode. I add a breakpoint at the `driver.get()` line, then run the script in debug mode.

This will allow you to step through the code.

[image]

When running to the breakpoint, it will open the browser, click **step into(F11)** and it will navigate to the specified web page.

[image]